# Doubt while finding the range of $f(x)=\cos^2x+4\sec^2x$ using the AM-GM inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I was asked to find range of
$$f(x)=\cos^2x+4\sec^2x$$

I converted the given expression to-

$$f(x)=\cos^2x+\frac{4}{\cos^2x}$$
and then applied AM-GM inequality but when I checked whether  equality will hold or not I found that for equality $\cos x=\pm\sqrt{2}$ which is not possible, therefore I can't find range of expression from here.

But when I repeated the same procedure by writing $f(x)=4\sec^2x+\frac{1}{\sec^2x}$. I found that inequality condition is also satisfied and I can easily write range.

I want to know why I can't get range from my first try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got good answers, you need equality also to happen when using AM-GM to get the minimum.  Heres one way to do use AM-GM here: as $\cos^2 x \leqslant \sec^2x$ with equality possible only when both $=1$, you can get a hint as to how to apply AM-GM.

$$f(x) = (\cos^2x + \sec^2x)+3\sec^2x \geqslant 2+3=5$$

where equality is when $\cos^2x=1 \iff x = n \pi$ for $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: means I apply a-m g-m for for terms in first bracket and then and then add $3sec^2x$

Comment: That's correct, the rest has minimum $3$, which is also achieved exactly when the AM-GM has equality.

Comment: best answer I would accept it whole-heartedly

Answer (score 2):

The inequality condition is still not satisfied. $\sec x\neq \pm \frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$ as range of $\sec x$ is $(-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty)$.

My advice would be to write the expression as $(\cos x+ 2\sec x)^2-4$ and try to proceed from there.

Comment: Oh yes silly me thanks for answering

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your query, consider accepting/upvoting the answer.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Shouldn't be $(\cos x+2\sec x)^2-4$ ?

Comment: Yes thanks, edited

Answer (score 1):

As $|\sec x| \geq 1$, AM-GM still does not give the solution. As you have to find the range,

Note that $f(x) = \cos^2 x + 4 \sec^2 x \geq 0$.

We rewrite as $f(x) = (\cos x - 2 \sec x)^2 + 4 \geq 5$.

as $|\cos x - 2\sec x| \geq 1$ (can you see why?) and equality occurs at $x = n \pi$.

Comment: You chose a plus sign between $cosx$ and $secx$ while above answer choose minus sign please explain

Comment: "can you see why?" please tell

Comment: The above answer writes $(\cos x + 2 \sec x)^2 - 4$ but I write $(\cos x - 2 \sec x)^2 + 4$. For example, when $\cos x$ is positive, $\cos x \leq 1$ and $\sec x \geq 1$. So to minimize, $|\cos x - 2 \sec x|$, we take maximum of $\cos x$ and that minimizes  $\sec x$. That gives us min of $|\cos x - 2 \sec x|$ as $1$. Similarly when $\cos x$ is negative.